# creating cell class then grid class with 2d array of cells

Tags: java, arrays

I am having troubles trying working on my homework assignment for my java course. The assignment is asking me to create a java class named Cell. The cell class has one integer instance variable that holds a positive value. Ive created methods to get the value and to set the value. I have also over writed the equals method to check if two different objects hold the same value.

Next I am supposed to create a Grid class that has an instance variable of a 2D array of cell objects.

The user can create a Grid specifying the number of row and column. 
Also the user can create a Grid specifying the size only.

I should also be creating a method to check if all the cells in the 2d array is empty.

I should be able to set all cells with default value of 0.

I should also be able to set specific cells with any positive number

Here's what i have so far:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQVPu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO8du.png)

Comment: I suggest you to post your code here in the format of markdown, instead of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Every cell is an object, 0 is an integer. I'd suggest you use your setter to set a new value like the following :

```
grid[i][j].setValue(0);
```

EDIT : And be sure that every cell in your grid has been instantiates prior to calling the setAll function. Otherwise, every grid element will be set to null.